# массив с двоичным кодом

Tags: python, массивы

не понимаю почему выдается ошибка в коде??

```
my_list = [11001010, 100101011, 01010101]
print ( my_list )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно так.

```
my_list = ['11001010', '100101011', '01010101']
```

Число не может начинаться с 0.

Comment: В Python 2 таки может, кстати

Comment: Ну и print(my_list) правильнее.

Comment: пробелы игнорируются же

Comment: `my_list = [0b11001010, 0b100101011, 0b01010101]`

Comment: DanilaKalivan, да, но PEP8 рекомендует без пробелов.